# Every time I deploy AngularDart app, Intellij starts indexing

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, angular-dart

Every time I use this to build my AngularDart 5 app,

`webdev build --output web:public`

IntelliJ starts indexing:

[image]

this takes a long time, during which many IntelliJ features do not work well. Why is IntelliJ doing this and how can I build without IntelliJ indexing?

Comment: If any of the project files are updated externally, it will force reindex. The only way to avoid it is to exclude the directories with externally modified files from the project.

Comment: yes, marking the public directory as excluded fixed it. thank you! please write it as an answer so that I can accept.